# Demarcation of a specific city

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am interested to demarcate the boundary of a specific city and then work on the data collected from that city in QGIS. But I am unable to specify boundaries of the required city from the vast google satellite imagery.
Can you please tell me how can I demarcate a whole specific city in QGIS?

Comment: I guess from your question you're looking for a specific city polygon boundary, isn't it ? If yes, this is data. You can find administrative boundaries in different websites. You will then have to load a polygon layer in QGIS and maybe select your specific city. Then only after will you be able to work on it.